# Convert two arrays into an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, functional-programming, ramda.js

```
var foo = { "a": [1,2,3] }
var bar = { "b": [7,8,9] }
```

output should look like this

```
[ {a: 1, b: 7}, {a: 2, b: 8}, {a:3, b: 9}]
```

How can I do this using ramda or javascript functional programming ?

I have done this using for loop i = 0, is it possible using functional ramda programming

Answer (score 2):

If both arrays are always the same length, you can do this using `map`.

```js
function mergeArrays(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.map(function(item, index) {
    return {
      a: arr1[index], //or simply, item
      b: arr2[index]
    };
  });
}

var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [7, 8, 9];

var joined = mergeArrays(a, b);

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(joined, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="result">
  
</pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using [`R.transpose`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#transpose) to convert an array of `[[1,2,3], [7,8,9]]` to `[[1, 7], [2, 8], [3, 9]]` and then map over it with [`R.zipObj`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipObj).

```js
const fn = R.compose(
  R.map(R.zipObj(["a", "b"])),
  R.transpose
)

const a = [1, 2, 3], b = [7, 8, 9]

const result = fn([a, b])

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

If you would prefer to pass `a` and `b` as two arguments to `fn` rather than an array then you can swap `R.transpose` in the example above with `R.unapply(R.transpose)`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want `[{a:1,b:7},{a:2,b:8},{a:3,b:9}]` it can be done pretty easily with map using the index to get the value in b:

```
var result = a.map((v, i) =>({ a: v, b: b[i] }));
```

Answer (score 0):

i am having an array

> const peopleObject = {   "123": { id: 123, name: "dave", age: 23 },
>   "456": { id: 456, name: "chris", age: 23 },   "789": { id: 789, name:
>   "bob", age: 23 },   "101": { id: 101, name: "tom", age: 23 },   "102":
>   { id: 102, name: "tim", age: 23 } }

for this particular i have created a code that convrts array to object i hope this is usefull for you

```
const arrayToObject = (array) =>
   array.reduce((obj, item) => {
     obj[item.id] = item
     return obj
   }, {})
const peopleObject = arrayToObject(peopleArray)
console.log(peopleObject[idToSelect])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output doesn't have a valid format. You should store the data in array. Like ,

```
var output = [];
var a = [1,2,3], b = [7,8,9];
for(var i=0; i< a.length; i++){
  var temp = {};
  temp['a'] = a[i];
  temp['b'] = b[i];
  output.push(temp);
}
```

You cannot store the result in an object the way you want. Objects are key-value pairs. But what you expect is only the values without keys which is not possible!

Answer (score 0):

create function form ramda's `addIndex` and `map`

```
const data = { keys: ['a', 'b', 'c'], values: ['11', '22', '33'] }

const mapIndexed = R.addIndex(R.map)

const result = mapIndexed((item, i) => {
  return { [item]: data.values[i] }
}, data.keys)
```

You will get an array of objects